# How can I exclude Spring beans scanned from a project's dependency?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management

I have a Gradle-based project with two modules `mod1` and `mod2`. Both are Spring Boot projects. `mod1` has `mod2` as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':mod2')
    //more deps
}
```

Both `mod1` and `mod2` classes base package is `com.project`. In `mod2`, I have some Spring MVC controllers under `com.project.controllers`, so when I start `mod1`, `mod2` controllers are registered in the Spring context.

I want to avoid that.

I have tried excluding them using `exclude` parameter of `@SpringBootApplication`, but it's not working (because they are inside another module/dependency and not in the project itself, I guess).

Is it possible to exclude `mod2`'s `com.project.controllers` package somehow by Gradle configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as far as I know. Gradle sees `mod2` as a dependency so it will pull in *everything* including any of its dependencies depending how you declared them in `mod2`'s `build.gradle` file.

Since they're part of the same package they will be automatically picked up by Spring, really the only way as far as I know to exclude individual components from the auto-scan is the explicitly specify the ones you want to exclude via [`excludeFilters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#excludeFilters--):

```
excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {MyController.class, MyOtherController})
```

Otherwise you will need to declare those specific controllers as a separate dependency that can be excluded when you pull in `mod2`:

`build.gradle` for `m2`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':mod2') {
        exclude 'controllers'
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` for `m1`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':controllers')
}
```

Something like that. I'm not a Gradle expert so refer to the docs:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:excluding_transitive_module_dependencies
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction_dependency_management.html

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the difference between `@SpringBootApplication`'s "exclude" parameter and `@ComponentScan`'s "excludeFilters"? I have tried the first one and it's not working. About creating another "controllers" module, it's not possible for me to do that, but thank you anyway.